# sending less references to a function

Tags: php

My lecturer didn't feel like explaining why this works so I need help about it.
Can't see why it pushes to `$second` the "Hello world".
code:

```
declare(strict_types = 1);
require "index.html";
$first = 10;
$second = 20;

function swap(&$value1, &$value2 = "Hello World") {
    $temp1 = $value1;
    $value1 = $value2;
    $value2 = $temp1;
}

swap($first, $second);
echo "<pre><u>Swap with 2 arguments</u>\nFirst: ".$first."\nSecond: ".$second."\n\n"; 

swap($first);
echo "<u>Swap with 1 arguments</u>\nFirst: ".$first."\nSecond: ".$second."</pre>";<br>
```

after the first run of the function the value in `$first` is 20, sending `$first` again should have given there 20 but it shows 10 and for some reason it prints "Hello world" while calling `$second` in the second echo.

Comment: In the second case `$first` should contain "Hello World" and `$second` should still be 10 from the first swap.

Comment: Because you're not passing in a value on the second function call. Therefore, it takes "Hello World" as the default. However, that value is never set in `$second`, as you're not passing it in on the second call.

Comment: In regards to your edit, `$first` has Hello World, `$second` has 10. See https://3v4l.org/Bm6F1

Comment: The first call to SWAP swapped the values so first=20 and second=10

Comment: @aynber thank you very much now it came all clear to me :)